# Jekyll did not generate _config.yml file and other directories except _sites directory. How to get them?

Tags: github, jekyll

After Jekyll build,

Jekyll did not generate `_config.yml` file and other directories except `_sites` directory.

How to get them?

```
$ jekyll build
```

Generated `_sites` folder, `index.html`.

Do I need manually create the files/folders `_config.yml, _drafts, _includes, _layouts, _posts, _data`?

Comment: Can you give us more infos about your problem.
_config.yml is not supposed to be part of the build result. So, what are you looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have skipped `jekyll init yoursite` to set up the base project structure in the directory `yoursite`.

Comment: I think you mean `jekyll new yoursite` but...yeah.